# Celery workers work 5 minutes later when receive tasks

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a scheduled task per 5 minutes, but the celery worker completes the work 5 minutes later, rather than completes it once has received it.

```
[2018-05-11 15:05:00,501: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mimir.core.task.batch_send_share_message.batch_send_member_sent_share_template_message[53e836d3-ac94-42f5-b79e-c525d5e43b15]  ETA:[2018-05-11 15:10:00.170054+08:00] 
[2018-05-11 15:10:00,210: INFO/MainProcess] Task mimir.core.task.batch_send_share_message.batch_send_member_sent_share_template_message[53e836d3-ac94-42f5-b79e-c525d5e43b15] succeeded in 0.0213618567213s: None
```

Comment: I just see a story.... what exactly is your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide the code that you're using in the body of the question and also be as specific as possible at what the issue is and what the actual output should be

Comment: Shouldn`t the celery worker work its task once it received the task?It received a task at 15:05 and completed at 15:10,but there is another task at 15:10 it should complete.

Comment: You are setting `eta`(expected time of arrival) in your task: `ETA:[2018-05-11 15:10:00.170054+08:00]` which tells celery worker to start the task at the set `eta`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the celery documentation on [ETA and Countdown](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown).
From the documentation:

> The ETA (estimated time of arrival) lets you set a specific date and
>   time that is the earliest time at which your task will be executed

If you want the worker to execute the task immediately it receives it, then you should not be setting `eta` in your task.